# How to sum the column, only if the vector is '>0'?

Tags: r

I wonder how to sum all the column, only if the vector is bigger than '0'.

I've got 'DF' like this.

```
A   B 
-14 4
-13 4
-12 3
-4  4
-1  4
0   4
1   4
2   3
3   4
4   4
.
.
.
```

And I want to A*B, especially if the vector is '>0'. So finally I want to get sum of `'1*4, 2*3 , 3*4 , 4*4'`.

What I tried is this

```
exp<- function(x){
 a<-c()
 for (y in c(1:nrow(DF)){
  if (DF[y,A]>0) {
 return (a<-c(a, DF[y,A] * DF[y,B]))
}
 else if (DF[y,A]<=0) {
 return (a<-c(a,0))
}
 result <- sum(a)
 result
}
```

But I think this code is too heavy. Especially the 'for in' code makes this function too slow. How can I make this code simpler?

Comment: How many columns do you have and is it always based on A?

Comment: @NelsonGon  Actually I have 20 cols and 100 thousand rows. One specific col must be base of this calculation. :)

Comment: Try this with `dplyr`, drops rows though: `df %>% 
 filter(A>0) %>% 
  mutate_at(-1,function(x) sum(x * .$A))`. Can replace`mutate_at` with `summarise_at`. Can also user `data.table`(It's relatively fast(er)).

Answer (score 1):

Try subsetting the data frame to only include rows in the sum both of whose `A` and `B` values are positive:

```
sum(df[df$A > 0 & df$B > 0, "A"]*df[df$A > 0 & df$B > 0, "B"])

[1] 38
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(-14,-13,-12,-4,-1,0,1,2,3,4),
                 B=c(4,4,3,4,4,4,4,3,4,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `base R` possibility could be:

```
sum(with((df > 0) * df, A * B))

[1] 38
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(DF)
DF[A > 0, sum(A*B)]
```

Or a similar solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

DF%>%
  filter(A > 0)%>%
  summarize(C = sum(A * B))
```